# What are more sensible, alternative ways to extract group names from RegExpMatchArray.groups

Tags: regex, typescript

I have managed *a* method -shown here- using util's inspect

```typescript
    private _returnTokensFromDefinitionMatch(match:RegExpMatchArray, document: vscode.TextDocument): IParsedToken[] {
        let tokens:IParsedToken[] = []
        let groupsNames = []
        for (let matches of inspect(match.groups).matchAll(/\s*(.*?):\s/g)){
            groupsNames.push(matches[1])
        }
        groupsNames.shift()
        for (let key of groupsNames) {
            let groupName:regexGroup = {
            name: key,
            length: match.groups[key].length,
            index: match.indices.groups[key][0],
            content: match.groups[key]
        }
    }
```

But this *can't* be the way you are supposed to extract these. I refuse to believe there isn't a better way.

compilerOptions if relevant

```json
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2022",
        "lib": ["es2022"],
        "outDir": "out",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false
    }
```

I spent a day bashing my head against the problem, searching around, trying to figure out how to get it to yield those strings to me. I looked into .keys() .entries(), and when I searched "[key:string]: string" and all I got was how to add such things, not how to retrieve the key later. I searched more than that but these three were the ones I felt most hopeful about.

I then gave up and decided I would do the stupid thing I was confident should at least work: just do whatever log does to produce the string and regex the group names out of that.

Comment: `Object.keys(match.groups)`? It's just an object, basically; available since `es2018`: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3fca8c842a42bb43ba5a86dcce1b7fb0eae6c7a4/src/lib/es2018.regexp.d.ts#L1-L5.

Comment: I don't know how I would use that information to extract the key's string. I was unable to get it to accept doing anything other than providing it a key value

Comment: What do you mean _"the key's string"_? If you mean you want the key _and the value_, use `entries` instead of `keys` to get both. Again, it's just an object.

Comment: In the `[key:*string*]: string` construction I want the \*string\*. RegExpMatchArray.groups.keys() tells me keys is not callable. I try putting anything in the parentheses and it tells me keys() "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1."

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand what Object meant or how to use it. Thank you. I started working with TypeScript (and by extension js like 3 days ago) I had been trying to fill in Object with a thing I had already, as I thought it was being a generic 'whatever your thing is' especially when the examples I find are written like Object.keys(obj)